# Equivalent conditions to "$P(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $u$ over $K$"

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

Let $K$ be a subfield of $F$, $u \in F $ be an algebraic element over $K$ and $P(x) \in K[x]$ be a monic polynomial. 
Show that:

> $P(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $u$ over $K$ if and only  ***either*** $P(x)$ is irreducible over $K$ and $P(u)=0$
>   ***or*** $P(x)$ is the polynomial in $K[x]$ of the least positive degree such that $P(u)=0$
>   ***or***    $ \deg(P(x))=[K(u):K]$ and $P(u)=0$.

I just want you guys show me the connection of the last statement with the 2 previous ones which seem obvious!

Comment: My confusion is mostly in the last part. Sorry I just want you guys show me  the connection of the last statement with the 2 previous ones which seem obvious.

@Watson lesson learned!

Comment: The statement appears to be badly formulated. I think what is asked to show is that the three statements separated by ***or*** are all equivalent, and equivalent to the fact that $P$ is minimal polynomial of $u$ over $K$. If that is intended, you should not use the "either ... or ... or ..." formulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your notations, here are $3$ statements, which you have to show to be equivalent to each other:

> 1. $P(x)$ is irreducible over $K$ and $P(u)=0$
> 2. $P(x)$ is the polynomial in $K[x]$ of the least positive degree such that $P(u)=0$
> 3. $\text{deg}(P(x))=[K(u):K]$ and $P(u)=0$.

(If $P$ satisfies one of these conditions, then it is called the minimal polynomial of $u$ over $K$).

According to your comment, you only need to handle with $(3)$.

— Let's see $3 \implies 2$. Suppose that $Q \in K[x]$ is a monic polynomial such that $Q(u)=0$, and let's show that its degree is greater or equal to the degree of $P$. To do this, assume that this is not the case: $r:=\text{deg}(Q)<\text{deg}(P)$. Then can you find a basis of $K(u)$ over $K$? Can you proceed from here?

Hint:

> Try $\{1,u,u^2,\dots,u^{r-1}\}$. It has $r<\text{deg}(P)$ elements, contradicting $(3)$…

— As for $2 \implies 3$, you only have to find a basis of $K(u)$ over $K$ which has cardinality $n:=\text{deg}(P)$. I let you think about it!

Comment: I've already solved this :)

Comment: @GodgogArsenal: so is my answer fine? Do you need more help?

Comment: It helps for sure ! I got the idea of finding the basis of $K(u)$ over $K$ and everything seem softer then

Comment: I am on the beginning of studying field and Galois theory, so loads of problem is following anyway, hope your help!